# Strange DataGridView Issue

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to make use of a DataGridView in C# to display data nicely in a table. I'm having this weird problem where the column headers won't resize automatically. It is weird because I copy the code into a new project and it works fine. The problem might be that I am adding the DataGridView to a TabPage (both of which are created programmatically at run-time). Here is the code:

```
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
grid.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 550);
grid.AutoSize = true;

grid.Columns.Add("1", "Col1");
grid.Columns.Add("2", "Col1");
grid.Columns.Add("3", "A longer name for col3");
grid.Columns.Add("4", "Col4");
grid.Columns.Add("5", "Col5");

grid.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5");

tabs.TabPages[tabIndex].Controls.Add(grid);
```

Here is the result:

[image: Initial result]

This occurs after I drag the row divider to resize the header:

[image: After resizing header manually]

Please keep in mind that the tab pages are created programmatically just before the above code is executed. Also, the code works fine when I don't place the DataGridView in a TabPage.

Is anyone able to help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution, in case anyone is having the same issue. All I had to do was something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grid.Columns)
    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
```

After this, the column headers size properly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be solved when you use `grid.Dock` instead of `grid.AutoSize`. You may need to change the width of `grid.MaximumSize`. Please check it out.

```
grid.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 550);
grid.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue :(